# Dump shared memory

Tags: memory, shared

Is it possible to dump and investigate shared memory content from Linux? I spoted some strange shared memory segments in a "ipcs -m" output and want to see what is in there. 
Also is it possible to determine the creator of this segment. "nattch" seems to be always zero.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this tool

[Shmcat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shmcat/)

It's a good tool for your purpose.

What do you mean with creator? Do you mean the PID of the process? In this last case you can use

```
ipcs -mp
```

You'll get this output:

```
------ Shared Memory Creator/Last-op --------
shmid      owner      cpid       lpid
3211265    root       1857       1866
```

where

```
CPID 
The process ID of the job that created the shared memory segment.
```

and

```
LPID 
The process ID of the last job to attach or detach from the shared memory segment or change the semaphore value.
```

**Edit:**

I don't think is possible to log those informations with standard tools.

I think we can do in this way.

Suppose we execute the command:

```
ipcs -m
```

and get these results

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 3211265    root      644        80         2
```

Then, with the command grep 3211265 /proc/*/maps, we obtain:

```
/proc/1862/maps:bla bla bla rw-s 00000000 00:09 3211265                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
/proc/1863/maps:bla bla bla rw-s 00000000 00:09 3211265                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
```

In this way we get the processes that was attached to the segment.

Scanning the elements in /proc/*/maps, you are able to discover the PIDs that are currently attached to a given segment.

You can make use of bash script that log these particular information.

Comment: Thank you for explainig what CPID and LPID are. But is it possible to log them somehow? Because by the time i detect this segment "ps aux | egrep CPID|LPID" gives nothing.
And i guess "ipcs  -mp" command itself changes the LPID?

Comment: Did you try? What's the situation?

Comment: I can't make a bash script which will catch the PID. First tried with "sleep 1", then even without and still didn't catch.

Comment: My idea is to create a script that executes some commands in pipe, then redirect the output to a file in append and run this script with cron.